# select distinct and count distinct in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Is this possible Selecting distinct rows from a table column and count repeated row for each distinct fields in a single query

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT location and COUNT(DISTINCT location) 
        FROM ".$db_name.".$table_name 
        ORDER BY location ASC 
        LIMIT ". $start_page.",". $recordPer_page."";
```

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT(location), COUNT(DISTINCT(location)) FROM ....

Answer (score 3):

Hi this query help you:

[**SQLFIDDLE example**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/35005/5)

```
SELECT   `location`, COUNT(`location`) 
    FROM     tbl   
    GROUP BY `location`
    ORDER BY `location`
```

Data:

```
    ('Africa'),
    ('Viena'),
    ('Mexico'),
    ('Chicago'),
    ('Miami'),
    ('Chicago'),
    ('Viena'),
    ('London'),
    ('Viena');
```

Result:

```
| LOCATION | COUNT(`LOCATION`) |
--------------------------------
|   Africa |                 1 |
|  Chicago |                 2 |
|   London |                 1 |
|   Mexico |                 1 |
|    Miami |                 1 |
|    Viena |                 3 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
SELECT   `location`, COUNT(DISTINCT `location`) 
FROM     ....   
GROUP BY `Location`
ORDER BY ....
LIMIT    ....
```

Comment: returns 1 in second column for all rows.